# how do you read the body content of HttpResponse object in C#/ ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, http

How do you read the content of an [HttpResponse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) object in C# / ASP.net?

I need to be able to read the body content as a JSON object, modify it, and then write it back to the response output stream.  I want to make sure I don't lose what's already in the stream, thus I need to read from it first.

How do I do this?

Comment: Have you attempted to write any code to handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a Delegating handler

```
public class ContentHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken).ContinueWith<HttpResponseMessage>((responseToCompleteTask) =>
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = responseToCompleteTask.Result;
            var YourContent = response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result;
            response.Content = new CompressedContent(response.Content, acceptedEncoding);
            return response;
        },
        TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion);
    }
}
```

Register your handler at WebApiConfig

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.MessageHandlers.Add(new ContentHandler());
```

You can edit your reponse content by extending the HttpContent Class.
For example to compress content

```
    public class CompressedContent : HttpContent
{
    private HttpContent originalContent;

    protected override bool TryComputeLength(out long length)
    {
        length = -1;

        return false;
    }

    protected override Task SerializeToStreamAsync(Stream stream, TransportContext context)
    {
        Stream editedStream = null;

        if (encodingType == "gzip")
        {
            editedStream = new GZipStream(stream, CompressionMode.Compress, leaveOpen: true);
        }
        else if (encodingType == "deflate")
        {
            editedStream = new DeflateStream(stream, CompressionMode.Compress, leaveOpen: true);
        }

        return originalContent.CopyToAsync(editedStream).ContinueWith(tsk =>
        {
            if (editedStream != null)
            {
                editedStream.Dispose();
            }
        });
    }
}
```